# Is this hard drive still usable?

Tags: hard-drive, fsck

I wanted to check the health of an older hard drive after it fell from a small height (~20 cm). `smartctl -l selftest` logged the following self tests:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===  
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1  
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error  
\# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     10728         225080
```

However `smartctl -A` gave following output:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===    
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16    
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:    
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE    
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       1063    
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0    
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   061   044   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       12000    
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3935    
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0    
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0    
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0    
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10728    
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0    
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0    
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3918    
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       30835999    
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       161    
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0    
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   059   044   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 11/58)    
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0    
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0    
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6    
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0    
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       14    
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       37    
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0    
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       111034
```

In particular these results:

```
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0   
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0    
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
```

Doesn't this mean while there are 6 bad sectors waiting to replaced, no other sectors have ever been replaced? Isn't there a way to tell the HDD to replace the bad sectors? Can I define 'unused sectors', so the HDD can use them to replace the bad sectors? Or shouldn't I bother to get more life out of this HDD?

I've done the recommended steps described by @heynnema and this are the results:

```
sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdb1  
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)  
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)  
Testing with random pattern: done                                                   
test: Updating bad block inode.  
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes  
Pass 2: Checking directory structure  
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity  
Pass 4: Checking reference counts  
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

test: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****  
test: 11/122101760 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 7713426/488378390 blocks
```

Comment: Looks like an early-stage-of-dying hard drive to me. Replace it immediately. You might want to wait...but how much of your data are you prepared to lose forever when your disk dies at the worst possible time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test your disk for bad blocks, and to map out any bad blocks found...

```
Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!
```

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.

   -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
          used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
          same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: Thanks for the instructions, it took about 18 hours to complete the recommended test. I've updated OP with the results. A few questions remain however, is that all I have to do to get rid of the bad blocks? Will those results carry over if I format the HDD to NTFS or will I have to repeat the process?

Comment: @UmBottesWillen yes, that's all that you have to do to get rid of the current bad blocks. Keep an eye on the SMART Data, to see if other problems continue, indicating a pending drive fail. And yes, you can safely create a new NTFS partition.

Comment: The SMART test still fails after 10% with the same error message, so I don't know what to think of that.

Comment: @UmBottesWillen  The SMART test uses a special part of the disk for testing, separate from the partition where you did the bad block scanning. This special area of the disk may have some damage due to the fall... esp if the drive was spinning at the time. I'd carefully go ahead and try to use the drive, monitoring the SMART Data. Understand that the drive may be unreliable.